# segmentation fault en c++ con mysql connector

Tags: c++

Buen dia, soy muy nuevo en el ambiente de programación y estoy haciendo unos programas de prueba.

Estoy usando c++ en codeblocks y mysql connector. Este es un segmento del código. Lo que quiero hacer es mandar el valor de la variable "t" que va aumentando cada ciclo. Pero obtengo segmentation fault antes de llegar al ultimo if(!qstate).

Espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar mi error o alguna sugerencia para evitarlo. Saludos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{



MYSQL*  conn;
MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL_RES* res;

int qstate; //stores query status after execution

conn = mysql_init(0);

if(conn)            // if SUCCEEDED
{
    cout<<"connection object ok"<<endl;
    }
else
{
    cout << "conn object problem!" <<mysql_error(conn) << endl;

    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn,"localhost","root","1234","prueba2",0,NULL,0);
    }

if(conn)            // if SUCCEEDED
{
    cout<<"connection to database done!!"<<conn<<endl;

    //before select, it will insert first. So new record will be displayed

 wiringPiSetup();
pinMode(0,OUTPUT);
pinMode(24,INPUT);



int a = 0;
    for (a = 0; a = 1; a+ digitalRead(24))
    {
float t;

    if(digitalRead(24) == HIGH)
    {

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0;i<3;i++)
        {
    digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
    delay(900);
    cout <<"Enciende"<<endl;
    digitalWrite(0,LOW);
    delay(900);
    cout <<"Apaga"<<endl;
        }
        t=t+a;
    cout<<t<<endl;
    }


    stringstream ss;
    ss<<t<<endl;

    string t2 = ss.str();

   string query="insert into tabla2 (id) values('"+ t2+"')";

    //const char converst string object to const char as it is requires in mysql_query(conn,q)
    const char * q = query.c_str();

    cout<<"query is: "<<q<<endl;
    qstate = mysql_query(conn,q);



    if(!qstate) //if insert succeeded
        cout<<"record inserted successfully..."<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"query problem: "<<mysql_error(conn)<<endl;
    // dasdsa
    //now lets run select query on db table
    qstate = mysql_query(conn,"select * from tabla2");

    if(!qstate)  //means nonzero
    {
       //get records from conn object to res* pointer
       res = mysql_store_result(conn);
       //now read an display record one @ time
       while(row=mysql_fetch_row(res))
       {
        cout<<"id: "<<row[0]<<endl;



    }
    }

else
    {
        cout << "query execution problem!" <<mysql_error(conn) << endl;
    }
   //its done
   }
    }
 else
 {
    cout << "conn object problem!" <<mysql_error(conn) << endl;

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Has inicializado `mysql`? ¿Has creado una conexión a una base de datos? ¿Eres capaz de lanzar consultas de búsqueda (selects)?

Comment: Ya lo he iniciado y he hecho conexion a base de datos, pero ingresando datos por el comando cin. Lo que busco aqui es mandar una variable. Sobre consultas de busqueda eso no lo he hecho.

Comment: Con esa respuesta no me aclaras nada. ¿Eres capaz de lanzar consultas tipo "select" a la base de datos? Te lo digo porque me da que estás intentando lanzar consultas sin estar conectado realmente a ningún sitio.

Comment: Por otro lado no muestras dónde y cómo incializas `conn`, así que también es posible que esa variable no tenga el valor que esperas...

Comment: Ya he puesto el còdigo completo donde se muestra la parte donde se inicia la conexiòn a la base de datos. En este codigo el "segmentation fault" viene antes de la consulta tipo select.
Todo el còdigo para hacer la conexiòn ya lo probè con texto y no me diò ningùn problema, el detalle viene cuando quiero meter esa variable.
Si te es necesario puedo poner el otro còdigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
conn = mysql_init(0);

if(conn)            // if SUCCEEDED
{
    cout<<"connection object ok"<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "conn object problem!" <<mysql_error(conn) << endl;

    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn,"localhost","root","1234","prueba2",0,NULL,0);
}
```

Ahí estás haciendo lo siguiente:

Inicializas la conexión... si la inicialización es correcta entonces no haces nada y si falla intentas conectarte a la base de datos. La conexión a la base de datos has de realizarla cuando hayas podido inicializar la conexión y no al revés:

```
conn = mysql_init(0);

if(conn)            // if SUCCEEDED
{
    cout<<"connection object ok"<<endl;

    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn,"localhost","root","1234","prueba2",0,NULL,0);
}
else
{
    cout << "conn object problem!" <<mysql_error(conn) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ese era el problema. Jamas se me hubiera ocurrido, andaba buscando por otro lado. Supongo que lo transcribí mal. Gracias por haberte tomado la molestia de revisar todo. Saludos